# Matplotlib animation.save only works when called from __main__

Tags: matplotlib, animation

I have written a function which in principle does this:

```
def make_animation():
    nframes = 30
    arr = np.random.rand(30, 2, 2) * 255
    data = xr.DataArray(arr, [('time', np.arange(30)), ('x', [1, 2]), ('y', [0, 1])])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    quad = data.isel(time=0).plot.imshow(origin='lower',
                                     vmin=np.nanmin(data.values),
                                     vmax=np.nanmax(data.values))

    def update(i):
        ti = data.isel(time=i)
        quad.set_array(ti.data)
        return quad

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update,
                               frames=len(data.time), blit=False,
                               interval=50)
    anim.save('some_path', writer='ffmpeg', fps=2)
```

It works like a charm if I call this from `__main__` for any number of `nframes`. However, if I import this function into another module it writes the output file, but doesn't "fill" it when `frames` is too high. (Too high already means 50 frames, or so). This is the last log message:

```
 matplotlib.animation: MovieWriter.grab_frame: Grabbing frame.
```

I've tried to set the `save_count` parameter to the length of the time axis already, but it didn't change anything. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Pretty much impossible to know why it doesn't work for you without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, I tried my best to produce one...